# Epi server - make content area specific for block

Tags: model-view-controller, episerver, episerver-8

I would like to achieve the following thing-

Build a pagetype which has 3 different ContentArea's and that the user can put only a specific block type in each of these areas.

For example - ContentArea1 can only accept block type of "BlockType1", ContentArea2 can only accept "BlockType2" and so on. (It doesn't need to be generic, I can specify hard coded which type should fit in each Content Area.

Is it possible to achieve?
Maybe there is another way?
(I know you can create a property with the block type, but I want to use the same block in different places)

ps: using EPI-SERVER 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From version 8.0 of EPiServer there is better support for AllowedTypes.

The feature was also available before version 8, but was more limited.

In short, you decorate your ContentArea property with the AllowedTypes attribute and EPiServer takes care of the rest.

Read more about it here:

http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2015/2/the-new-and-improved-allowed-types/